# basic4android android.os.networkonmainthreadexception error

Tags: basic4android

Im trying to Contol LEDs using my android device and I'am using Basic4android for the app. I got things working but everytime I press a button to turn an LED on/off.. I got this error saying "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" ... This is my code:

```
Sub Process_Globals
    'These global variables will be declared once when the application starts.
    'These variables can be accessed from all modules.
     Dim request As HttpRequest
     Dim HttpClient1 As HttpClient
End Sub

 Sub Globals
'These global variables will be redeclared each time the activity is created.
'These variables can only be accessed from this module.

    Dim Button1 As Button
    Dim Button2 As Button
    Dim Button3 As Button
    Dim Button4 As Button
    Dim Button5 As Button
    Dim Button6 As Button
End Sub

Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean)
    Activity.LoadLayout("main")
    HttpClient1.Initialize("HttpClient1")
End Sub

Sub HttpClient1_ResponseSuccess (Response As HttpResponse, TaskId As Int)
    Dim resultString As String
    resultString = Response.GetString("UTF8")
End Sub

Sub HttpClient1_ResponseError (Response As HttpResponse, Reason As String, StatusCode As Int,     TaskId As Int)
    Log("Error connecting: " & Reason &" "& StatusCode)
    If Response <> Null Then
    Log(Response.GetString("UTF8"))
    Response.Release
    End If
End Sub

Sub Button6_Click
  request.InitializeGet("http://192.168.0.8/?BlueOFF")
  HttpClient1.Execute(request, 1)
End Sub

Sub Button5_Click
   request.InitializeGet("http://192.168.0.8/?BlueON")
   HttpClient1.Execute(request, 1)
End Sub

Sub Button4_Click
  request.InitializeGet("http://192.168.0.8/?GreenOFF")
  HttpClient1.Execute(request, 1)
End Sub

Sub Button3_Click
    request.InitializeGet("http://192.168.0.8/?GreenON")
    HttpClient1.Execute(request, 1)
End Sub

Sub Button2_Click
    request.InitializeGet("http://192.168.0.8/?RedOFF")
    HttpClient1.Execute(request, 1)
End Sub

Sub Button1_Click
    request.InitializeGet("http://192.168.0.8/?RedON")
    HttpClient1.Execute(request, 1)
End Sub
```

I've researched this issue and it says that I'am doing a network operation on the main thread... I'm new to basic4android.. any tips on how to do the network operations an a separate thread? any help is really appreciated.. thank you :D

best regards, 
Caldwell D.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions. The simplest would be to disable the strict mode on Android version greater API 9:

```
Sub DisableStrictMode
   Dim jo As JavaObject
   jo.InitializeStatic("android.os.Build.VERSION")
   If jo.GetField("SDK_INT") > 9 Then
     Dim policy As JavaObject
     policy = policy.InitializeNewInstance("android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder", Null)
     policy = policy.RunMethodJO("permitAll", Null).RunMethodJO("build", Null)
     Dim sm As JavaObject
     sm.InitializeStatic("android.os.StrictMode").RunMethod("setThreadPolicy", Array(policy))
   End If
End Sub
```

Better solution would be to replace the Response.GetString() calls (which are deprecated) with the Asynchronous Response.GetAsynchronously() calls.